# Out of bounds but it shouldn't

Tags: java

```
public class Ctrl {

    Graph g = new Graph(); 
    Edge[] edges = new Edge[g.getM()];
    int[] verteY = new int[g.getM()];
    int[] verteX = new int[g.getM()];
    int[] vCost = new int[g.getM()];
    int contor=0;

    public void add(int x,int y,int c) {
        System.out.println("contor:" + this.contor);
        System.out.println("M:" + g.getM());
        verteX[this.contor] = x;
        verteY[this.contor] = y;
        vCost[this.contor] = c;
        this.contor = this.contor + 1;
}
```

and the output is

```
contor:0
M:5
```

why do I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` then?

Comment: Are you sure `g.getM()` equals 5 when you create your arrays ?

Comment: yes,that setter is called before even reading another content.

Comment: Show the section of code where you call your add method and also where M is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems likely that a newly-initalized `Graph`'s `getM()` returns zero, making all four arrays zero-size.

If `g.getM()` later changes, the arrays don't automatically get resized.

My recommendation would be to use `ArrayList` instead of raw arrays. This would make it easy to append to them.

Comment: the value returned by `getM()` doesn't change,it's read from a file and stays like this.

Comment: @Matt: You are calling `getM()` on a newly constructed `Graph`, *before you read it from file*.